# Improve css text animation with heading and list

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transforms

This is is what I have coded so far [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mukherjiikunal/pen/xxLERvx).

Can ignore the background images and other elements. Just need to get the animation for the heading (i.e. in yellow) and the list below right. Any ideas on how to improve this?

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
  width: auto;
  transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

h1 span {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

@keyframes slideUpHeading {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 48px;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideUpHeading {
  animation-name: slideUpHeading;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 1, 2, 2);
}

@keyframes slideUpText {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.slideUpText {
  animation-name: slideUpText;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.88, 0.32, 1.5);
}

.animation_delay1 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.animation_delay2 {
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

.animation_delay3 {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.animation_delay4 {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

@keyframes slideUpList {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.slideUpList {
  animation-name: slideUpList;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 2.65s;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.88, 0.32, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="slideUpHeading">
  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay1">Lorem</span><br>
  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay2">ipsum</span><br>
  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay3">dolor sit</span><br>
  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay4">amet</span>
</h1>

<ul class="slideUpList">
  <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks good except bottom list animation delay. I have adjusted that along with all animation duration.. have a look.

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
  width: auto;
  transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

h1 span {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

@keyframes slideUpHeading {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 48px;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideUpHeading {
  animation-name: slideUpHeading;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s; /* It was 0.6s */
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 1, 2, 2);
}

@keyframes slideUpText {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.slideUpText {
  animation-name: slideUpText;
  animation-duration: 0.4s; /* It was 0.6s */
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.88, 0.32, 1.5);
}

.animation_delay1 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.animation_delay2 {
  animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

.animation_delay3 {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.animation_delay4 {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

@keyframes slideUpList {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.slideUpList {
  animation-name: slideUpList;
  animation-duration: 0.4s; /* It was 0.6s */
  animation-delay: 2.20s; /* It was 2.65s */
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.88, 0.32, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black&family=Fredoka+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="slideUpHeading">

  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay1">which</span><br>

  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay2">statement</span><br>

  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay3">best describes</span><br>

  <span class="slideUpText animation_delay4">you?</span> <!-- Added : question mark ;) -->

</h1>

<ul class="slideUpList">
  <li>Picking up a new skill</li>
  <li>Picking up a new skill</li>
  <li>Picking up a new skill</li>
  <li>Picking up a new skill</li>
</ul>
```

[Play here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/QWMKMgb)

Comment: thank you so much for this and now with the adjustments, it looks awesome! if there are no more suggestions I will select your post as the answer (:

Comment: yup! sure...  :)

Comment: Thank you so much Nimitt (: Please help to change the text to  "lorem ipsum" in your pen post. I have selected your solution as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: I might need some more help like this. Possible to tag you in new posts?

Comment: Also, suppose there is a need for a 5th line. So what kind of delay do you think I should add?

Comment: @Kunal - Sure, you can tag me. Also, I have added lorem ipsum text in my pen. Also added more than 4 lines. See [here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/QWMKMgb)